# Difference among omni.ja file in Firefox distribution

Tags: firefox

What is the difference (in content and purpose) among `omni.ja` files in Firefox distribution?

Current (43a) Nightly contains following omni.ja files (size and name):

```
12579582 ./browser/omni.ja
12210547 ./omni.ja
   84209 ./webapprt/omni.ja
```

Even though the sizes of `omni.ja` and `browser/omni.ja` are quite similar the files differs significantly in content as shows the diff http://pastebin.com/kRziazn4